# Recursive procedure gives segfault

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, nasm, factorial

I'm trying to make the Factorial procedure but it's not working for some reason.
I'm sorry, but I have literally no idea what the problem is. I tried debugging with gdb but I couldn't figure it out.

```
        push 4
        call Factorial

        exit
        
        Factorial:
            cmp byte [rsp + 8], 0
            jz end
            
            mov eax, [rsp + 8]
            mov ebx, eax
            dec ebx
            imul eax, ebx
            add rsp, 8
            push rbx
            call Factorial

            end:
                ret
```

Comment: Please commit every line of code with what you think it does.  One thing that immediately jumps to my eye is that `push rbx` is not matched with a corresponding `pop`, so the return from the recursive call goes to the number you have pushed interpreted as an address, likely causing a crash.  But the remaining logic also seems very fishy.  E.g., there is no code to return a meaningful value in the non-recursive case and I don't understand how that is supposed to work.

Comment: Also, please show the definition of the `exit` macro to make your code self-contained.  And please let us know what operating system you are programming for.

Comment: @fuz: It looks like the `add rsp,8` / `push` is an attempt to replace the stack arg instead of creating a new one.  But instead it overwrites the return address.  It could maybe work if the call/red tail-call was also transformed into a `jmp Factorial`, but at that point it's not recursive, and would still have to `mov [rsp+8], rbx` instead of add/push to leave the return address unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the calling convention of procedure `Factorial`.
Recursive procedures are better called with input/output in registers instead of pushed on stack.
I used your algorithm for 32bit Windows and debugged in OllyDbg, but it shouldn't be difficult to modify it for 64bit Linux.

```
user259137 PROGRAM Format=PE,Width=32,Entry=Start
  IMPORT ExitProcess,Lib=kernel32.dll
Start:
  MOV EAX,4
  CALL Factorial ; Returns factorial of EAX in EAX.
  PUSH EAX       ; Errorlevel to exit with.
  JMP ExitProcess
  
Factorial:        ; Returns factorial of EAX in EAX.  
    CMP EAX,1
    JNA end
    PUSH EBX      ; Do not clobber any reg but EAX.     
     MOV EBX,EAX
     DEC EAX
     CALL Factorial
     IMUL EAX,EBX
    POP EBX
end:RET
 ENDPROGRAM
```

Created with `euroasm.exe user259137.asm`.
Factorial can also be computed recursively at assembly time at macro-level, see [this example](https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t8233.htm).